# Why are not displayed string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**I created method "to_s" :**

```
  def to_s
    "#{self.name}:#{self.price}:#{self.weight}"
  end
```

**When I add products to the cart by "cart.add_item"**

```
@items = []
@items << AntiqueItem.new({:price => 111, :weight => 100, :name => 'car'})
@items << RealItem.new({:price => 111, :weight => 100, :name => 'kettle'})
@items << RealItem.new({:price => 200, :weight => 100, :name => 'dishwasher'})

cart = Cart.new('vitalik')

cart.add_item RealItem.new({:price => 111, :weight => 100, :name => 'car'})
cart.add_item RealItem.new({:price => 121, :weight => 100, :name => 'car'})
cart.add_item RealItem.new({:price => 151, :weight => 100, :name => 'kettle'})

p cart
```

**In the console information is not displayed string**

```
E:\work\storeapp3\app\storeapp\shop>ruby init.rb
#<Cart:0x2685888 @items=[#<RealItem:0x2685828 @weight=100, @real_price=111, @name="car">, #<RealItem:0x2685738 @weight=100, @real_price=121, @name="car">, #<RealItem:0x2685648 @wei
ght=100, @real_price=151, @name="kettle">], @owner="vitalik">
```

**Maybe I made a mistake somewhere?**

Comment: you defined the `to_s` method, but Why not use？

Comment: @pangpang because `to_s` is called implicitly by some methods outputting objects into stdout. For example by `puts`.

Comment: OP: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because [`p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p) displays the result of calling `inspect` method on object. You can use `puts` instead.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea p used `.inspect` natively, very nice!

Comment: @Marek Lipka, **Anyway not working**
`puts cart`
**in the console**
`E:\work\storeapp3\app\storeapp\shop>ruby init.rb
#<Cart:0x25818f0>`

Comment: @VitalikAndrysha are you sure you overwrote `to_s` method of `Cart` class?

Comment: @Marek Lipka, **This project see:** [https://github.com/Wallsays/LearnRuby/blob/master/storeapp/app/item.rb](https://github.com/Wallsays/LearnRuby/blob/master/storeapp/app/item.rb)

Comment: @VitalikAndrysha ok you defined `to_s` method for `Item` class. Why do you expect `Cart` instances to use it?

Comment: @Marek Lipka, **Did sonvertuvatys product is not yet in Item ? I only can not understand this, it works on video lessons, and I not working**

Comment: @VitalikAndrysha I don't understand your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78332/discussion-between-vitalik-andrysha-and-marek-lipka).